# Parametric Equation solving over integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, factoring

I have a question on my mind I am trying to solve. However I am stuck at a point. If you could help, I would be very pleased. $$\frac {x_2y_2z_2}{x_2y_2+y_2z_2+x_2z_2}=\frac {x_1y_1z_1}{x_1y_1+y_1z_1+x_1z_1}+6 $$
I have tried to solve this equation however I couldn't, by solving I mean finding $x_2,y_2,z_2$ in terms of $x_1,y_1,z_1$, and all of the terms must be integers. For instance for observation I tried doing it when $x_1=y_1=z_1$ and on solution became $x_2=x_1+18$ and similar for $y_1, z_1$. However I seemed to come to the conclusion that all three must be different: $x_1\neq x_2\neq x_3$, we can find solutions such as $x_2= y_1z_1+x_1+7$ however all of the terms $x_1,x_2, y_1,y_2, z_1,z_2$ must be positive integers.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the $+6$? Is there some reason you wouldn't be interested if there were a $+7$ on the right, instead?

Comment: Like I said I am trying to solve another problem in which this equation pops up. However, if you do for 7 illustrating your method I can try to copy it for 6 too.

Comment: "Like I said I am trying to solve another problem in which this equation pops up." So, what is the other problem?

Comment: I am trying to construct three positive integers x,y,z that satisfies the equation $4xyz=(24m+1)(xy+yz+xz)$, and I want the solution for all m, so I thought induction would work, that's how I got to that equation.

Comment: So, $${4\over24m+1}={1\over x}+{1\over y}+{1\over z}$$ You're working on the Erdos-Straus conjecture?

Comment: Yes, just a case I am stuck at, with 24m+1 and 24m+17.

Comment: The first step might be $\frac{4}{24m+1}=\frac{1}{6m+2}+\frac{7}{2(3m+1)(24m+1)}$. For the second term one could use a theorem on $\frac{m}{n}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$.

Comment: The cases that, so far as I know, are still unresolved are denominator congruent modulo 840 to 1, 121, 169, 289, 361, and 529 (yes, each of those is the square of an odd number). A reference is Mordell's book, Diophantine Equations.

Comment: Thanks, I found this myself but it seems that I have not made any progress, but I will struggle at least I do not have anything to do until school.